# Cleanest Way to Take A Date and Time Input And Create a Date (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

I would like to know the simplest way to get the date and time values from two html inputs, type="date" and type="time" pickers respectively. I want to merge into one complete Date string, I see I can

```
new Date(typeDate) -> date with gmt
```

but cannot

```
new Date(typeTime) -> invalid date
```

what is the simplest operation, ideally with utcString to maintain the timezone. Bonus is how to handle time without Date input and create a date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert html5 input type date and time to javascript datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640351/how-to-convert-html5-input-type-date-and-time-to-javascript-datetime)

Comment: Check 2nd answer of above question.